# Pandas upgrade from 1.5.3 to 2.1 returns key error on df.sum() even though key does exist

Tags: pandas, keyerror

I recently upgraded pandas 1.5.3 to 2.1.  I didn't change any code and a previous df.["Total"].sum() given below which previously ran fine now returns a key error on the word "Total" even though that key does exist and works fine on 1.5.3.

Grateful for any known issues on this when changing between versions.

I have tried checking that code runs fine on 1.5.3 and fails only on upgrade to >2.0.
I have checked the key "Total" does exist and is spelled correctly.

```
acount = stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev["Total"].sum() + stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev["Total"].sum()
```

stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev returns the DF below

```
        Type    Total
0   Drawings    118
1   Reports 8
2   Specifications  2
3   Contractor Submittals   2
```

stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev returns the DF below

```
        Type    Total
0   Drawings    65
```

acount correctly returns a value of 195

I have figured out why I get the key error.  when running exactly the same code but with pandas 2.1 the DF's are returned with completely different column names.  **what I don't know is why?**

stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev returns the DF below

```
fapcount    count
0   Drawings    65
```

stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev returns the DF below

```
    concount    count
0   Drawings    118
1   Reports 8
2   Specifications  2
3   Contractor Submittals   2
```

The problem seems to be that Pandas 2.1 doesnt rename the columns the same way as 1.5.3.  Below the code which creates the DF calling the "table function given below that;

```
stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev = table(df,'fapcount')
stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev = table(df,'concount')

def table(df,col):
    table = df[col].value_counts().to_frame()
    table = table.rename(columns={col: "Total"})
    table = table.reset_index()
    table = table.rename(columns={"index": "Type"})
    return table
```

df originates from a CSV file import;

```
df = pd.read_csv(filereads, skiprows=1)
```

The difference in operating seems to be in this line in def table()

```
table = df[col].value_counts().to_frame()
```

in 1.5.3 it returns;

```
concount
Drawings    118
Reports 8
Specifications  2
Contractor Submittals   2
```

in 2.1 it returns, and seems to add the count label automatically;

```
concount    count
Drawings    118
Reports 8
Specifications  2
Contractor Submittals   2
```

Comment: You have an extra unnecessary period: `df.["Total"].sum()` --> `df["Total"].sum()`. If this does not fix your issue, please provide more information and a reproducible example

Comment: Sorry thats just my typo in the message.  The code is correct because it runs fine in 1.5.3. The only change is the upgrade to 2.1 then throws the error.  Changing back it works fine again.  I cant find anything that points to why this would be

Comment: @CreditcruncherX, how about you show your code and make a [Minimal-Reproducible-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ?

Comment: I would do but its at the end of a very long piece of code and would have to upload so much to make it reproducable.

Comment: acount = stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev["Total"].sum() + stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev["Total"].sum()

It gives the key error on "Total"

Comment: Can you `print(stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev).columns` and  `print(stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev).columns` right before this line ?

Comment: Yes I did try that and it printed fine.  I will post a copy later when I have access to the full code

Comment: They both return
Index(['Type', 'Total'], dtype='object')

Comment: I have edited the original query above to include the sample code and DF and total values returned when running 1.5.3 but get key error on same code with 2.0

Comment: Yes i am just looking at this its almost as if the columns are not being renamed in 2.1 the same way they were in 1.5.3

Comment: Can you show how do you define `stat_not_on_conject_latest_rev` and `stat_not_on_conject_not_latest_rev` ?

Comment: Just added to original post above.

Comment: By the way Timeless thanks so much for the tip on the mini-reproducible.  I had not been aware of df.to_clipboard() which is actually what helped me realise the column names were different between the two versions.  Definitely a function that I will be using more often in development and debugging.  Really helpful thanks

Comment: If i change "Total" to "count" in subsequent code then of course the key error goes away and the file runs normally.  But I want to use "Total" and it works fine in 1.5.3.  So there is something different about the column renaming between the two versions which I would love to understand

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added an answer below to explain the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the function [`value_counts_internal`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L862) which returns on `2.0.0+` a Series with a default name (*i.e* `"count"`). You can check [*GH49912*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/49912) for more context/details.

```
def value_counts_internal(
    values,
    sort: bool = True,
    ascending: bool = False,
    normalize: bool = False,
    bins=None,
    dropna: bool = True,
) -> Series:
    from pandas import (
        Index,
        Series,
    )

    index_name = getattr(values, "name", None)
    name = "proportion" if normalize else "count"
    ...
```

Let's consider the example below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "fapcount": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "concount": [3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
})
```

On `1.5.3`, we get :

```
>>> df["fapcount"].value_counts()

2    2
3    2
1    1
Name: fapcount, dtype: int64
```

While, on `2.0.0+`, the Series has `"count"` as a name and the column name becomes the index name (*see below*) :

```
>>> df["fapcount"].value_counts()

fapcount
2    2
3    2
1    1
Name: count, dtype: int64 # <-- look at the name here !

>>> df["fapcount"].value_counts().index
Index([2, 3, 1], dtype='int64', name='fapcount')
```

That's why when you try to `table.rename(columns={col: "Total"})`, you're asking pandas to rename the passed column name (*which does not exist anymore*) with `"Total"` and since this will never happen, the `KeyError ["Total"]` is triggered when you try to select this column later on your code.

---

So, to solve your problem, you can slightly adjust your function `table` :

```
def table(df, col):
    return (
        df[col].value_counts()
            .rename_axis("Type")
            .reset_index(name="Total")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks timeless I reached the same conclusion in the end which I am pretty pleased about because I am just an amateur coder learning hard.  But it would have taken me some time to then work out the rest of your answer on the change to returning a series in >2.0, and the final change required to code.  Is that well documented in Pandas changes because I looked high and low and couldn't find it for something which seems pretty fundamental?

Comment: Thanks for your help and sticking with me.  Much appreciated

Comment: @CreditcruncherX, you're welcome. No, unfortunately it is not explicitly documented.

Comment: That being said, to fix the `KeyError` you need to adjust your function `table` as I mention in the end.

Comment: Got that and will do.  Thanks again